# Convert .csv to .sav file (SPSS format)

Tags: csv, export, spss

In google i found a lot of links, where i can convert .sav to .csv online, but i, actually, can't find any link or program, which can make next export ".csv -> .sav".

It's really need to use that kind of files in SPSS (i use SPSS 19 ver.) 'cause a lot of db's, finding in the internet, state information for next analysis in .csv format.

Does anyone know, is it real? If yes, where i can find that solution?

Answer (score 3):

To save a .csv file as a .sav file just open the .csv file in SPSS then go to Save As in the File menu and it will automatically select .sav as the default file type.

Comment: But in SPSS, when i open file, needed extension is missing.
And if i wanna open file, choose any type of file, then open .csv, it can't understand the format and don't open it normally

Comment: I've never encountered that before (rarely open .csv files in SPSS though). Could it be a problem with the .csv file itself? Can you provide a link to the .csv file?

Answer (score 0):

I have looked a lot of variants in internet, but nothing. So, the easiest way (as for me) - open .csv in excel, next one: save to excel standard format.
And then open saved with new extension file into SPSS, and, as it need, in .sav
Easy enough, but it's a little strange, that i really didn't find any normal ways to transform as scheme above.